# redirection to naked domain only

Tags: redirect, virtualhost, apache2.4

On my Apache 2.4 webserver I configured a vhost to redirect all requests on http to https and it works fine. I want to improve it by adding the following rule:

> if user request http://www.domain.example redirect to https://domain.example

My current vhost definition (the part applicable) is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.example [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.example
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=mail.domain.example
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

I understand that I have to change the `{SERVER_NAME}` part and presumably I have to put there

```
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.example%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

but this is a production environment and I cannot make test on this.

Comment: Are you getting any errors with this redirect?

Comment: No. But it redirects http://www.domain to https://www.domain while I now want it to redirect to https://domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to force both `https` and  `non-www` :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.domain\.example$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Replace `www.domain.example` with your real domain name in the first condition and make sure to restart your web server before testing this new rule.